# MySQL : between value in string

Tags: mysql, sql-like, between

I'm trying to build a query which matches the rows following these rules :

- my rows contents ids like 'MATCH_1', 'MATCH_2', 'MATCH_4'...
- I want to match the rows which id is between 2 boundaries: SELECT id FROM table WHERE id LIKE "MATCH_%", % must be between 2 and 5 for example. The result must be : 'MATCH_2', 'MATCH_4', 'MATCH_5'

Is it possible to do so ?

Thanks

Comment: And I suppose that `MATCH_10` is *not* between `MATCH_1` and `MATCH_2`, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you mean this?

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM table
  WHERE row 
BETWEEN 'MATCH_2' AND 'MATCH_5';
```

or converted to int

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table
   WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(row FROM 7) AS UNSIGNED)
 BETWEEN 2 AND 5;
```